# Testing new form from link returns error 404

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to test a form I made but when I paste the link https://www.cognitoforms.com/Alestra1/SOLICITUDDEGASOLINA in my google Chrome or IE I get a 404 message.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com). Initially, this feature was not made available in all countries. As our user base continues to expand, we will continue to add this usability to more countries. Our next release, scheduled for later this week, will add this ability for additional countries and your country is included. In the meantime, you can use your form’s Preview option to test your form, or you can use the embed code to add it to a web page.

Comment: We have expanded the countries that we are supporting public links with. You can check to see if you have access to your public link by checking the publish page.